# Python: all shortest paths in disconnected components of a graph

Tags: python, for-loop, error-handling, exception, networkx

I am computing all the possible shortest paths between any two nodes in a regular network. If the network is connected (e.g., largest component = entire network), I have no problems.

The problem arises when I have disconnected components: given that there is no path between node `n` and node `j`, a `NetworkXNoPath` error is raised.

**My problem:** **I want to skip all pairs of nodes that are not connected.** I know I need an `if` to check for the presence of the error being raised, but I don't know how to add it to my code.

My code for computing all the possible shortest paths between any two nodes in the graph:

```
    import networkx as nx
    counts=OrderedDict()
    for n in F.nodes(): counts[n]=0
    for n in F.nodes():
        for j in F.nodes():
            if (n!=j):
                gener=nx.all_shortest_paths(F,source=n,target=j)
                for p in gener:
                    for v in p: counts[v]+=1
```

**To recap:** I can use `nx.bidirectional_dijkstra(F, n, j)` to check for the existence of an edge between node `n` and node `j`, and it raises the `NetworkXNoPath`error if such edge is missing, but how can I check for this error so to skip a pair of non-connected nodes?

Comment: have your tried using try and except for this. you can do try:  nx.bidirectional_dijkstra(F, n, j)  except NetworkXNoPath: #do what you want.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to use it for this case, but I guess this is the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use error handling in python for this.

```
try:
  nx.bidirectional_dijkstra(F, n, j)
except NetworkXNoPath:
  # do whatever you want
```

you can use this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more help

Comment: There's actually an `nx.` missing but this works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just do the calculations for each connected component.  The test to see if there isn't a path between two nodes can be expensive.

```
connected_components = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)
for component in connected_components:
    #your code here.
```

Comment: but this is for [un-directed graphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html?highlight=connected_component_subgraph) only, how can we handle this in a directed graph?